# Building tabbed navigation drawer listview in React Native

Tags: android, listview, tabs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I have the present layout within Android encompassing a navigation drawer with tabbed listviews:

[image]

and

[image]

How can this interface be replicated in `React Native`?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the menu drawer can be built by using the `DrawerLayoutAndroid` component. Its API is quite simple (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html); if you only want it to respond to the menu button click (and not gestures) you have to set the `drawerLockMode` prop, you can open it programmatically by calling the `openDrawer` method. You wrap the Navigator component (for navigating between views) around this DrawerLayoutAndroid; see my post here for more information: [How can I change the scene(Navigator) by click DrawerLayoutAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753564/how-can-i-change-the-scenenavigator-by-click-drawerlayoutandroid/36412062#36412062)

To build the tabular view **with swiping gestures**, unless you want to build it all yourself from scratch (which is definitely possible) I recommend the following community project: **react-native-scrollable-tab-view** (https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view).